# Firestore Security Rules - are rules cascading downward?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using the first version of Firestore security rules:

`rules_version = '1';`

Also, I have the following rule:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /chats/{chatId} {
      allow read: if <condition1>
      allow write: if false;

      match /messages/{document=**} {
        allow read: if <condition2>
        // allow write: if false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have commented the write operation. Is the chat doc's write operation rule being passed to the match of messages documents? Do I need to explicitly write the condition for the write operation in the nested match? If not, if the write rule is not explicitly declared... will it be `false` by default?

---

## Update

I have read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data) that

> Security rules apply only at the matched path

so, we have to explicitly define the rules for the nested stuff... but, in the case of `write: if false`, if it is not declared, will it be false by default?

Answer (score 1):

If you comment some rule, it won't work. Rules works like in CSS for example. The last rule matters most. Here is a small example how you should secure dataase:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // {document=**} is equal to all collections and documents in whole database.
    // including nested ones, so use it wise.
    match /{document=**} { 
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    // Above i restrict access to whole database but here users
    // can do something in bookings collection.
    // They can make documents in this collection but cannot
    // make nested collections because of rule above.
    match /bookings/{docId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid || isAdmin()
      allow update: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid || isAdmin()
      allow create: if request.auth != null
    }
    match /app/{document} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}

function isAdmin() {
        return request.auth.token.admin == true;
}
```

Comment: So, if at the top level I do not have `match /{document=**} { ... }`, will anyone be able to create random collections in the root of the database? If not, by default undeclared rules would be `if false`, right?

Comment: @Raul Well database by default is closed you don't need to use first statement but in my opinion it shows well how database works. If you had like `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` in that brackets, every logged-in user can do anything with your database.

Comment: @Raul Rules works like if you deny access to something, it looks for permission. If you got permission, it just gives you what you requested, no matter that later you denied it.